# Wordpress Extend main profile tab Ultimate Member

Tags: wordpress

I want to make an extra tab in the profile overview of ultimate member.
I found this code and it creates indeed a new tab.
Now I want that when someone presses the tab, they are referred to a page on the website. 
Does anyone now how you can do it?

Here is the code that i found.

```
    add_filter('um_profile_tabs', 'add_custom_profile_tab', 1000 );
    function add_custom_profile_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['mycustomtab'] = array(
    'name' => 'Inschrijving Bivak',
    'icon' => 'um-faicon-pencil',
     );

     return $tabs;

    }

    add_action('um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default', 'um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default');
    function um_profile_content_mycustomtab_default( $args ) {
    echo 'Hello world!';
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

offtopic --> (altijd leuk zo'n bivak ^^)

---

I'm not very familiar with the Ultimate Member plugin.
But tabs almost always have a corresponding content box connected, you want it to behave differently then what it's intended for.

I think the most simple solution is a little jQuery function that does the redirect when you click the tab. That way you dont have to 'hack' the UM plugin.

Here's an example.
You can load this snippet on all pages if you want.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  if($('body.um-page-user').length) {
    $( ".um-profile-nav .um-profile-nav-register_bivak_tab a" ).on( "click", function() {
      window.location.href = "https://www.chirooostham.be/inschrijvingen/";
    });
  }
});
```

**VERSION 2:**
This replaces the href link, it may work better.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  if($('body.um-page-user').length) {
    $( ".um-profile-nav .um-profile-nav-register_bivak_tab a" ).attr('href', 'https://www.chirooostham.be/inschrijvingen/'); 
  }
});
```

---

In the filter change the tab key `mycustomtab` into `register_bivak_tab`.

Like this:

```
$tabs['register_bivak_tab'] = array(
  'name' => 'Inschrijving Bivak',
  'icon' => 'um-faicon-pencil',
);
```

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Hey Bjorn

Where do I have to place the lines of code? In a new snippet?
And where can I find the Tab Classname? I'm not familiar with this type of coding.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can use a [snippet plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/). Or you can use your own .js file.

Comment: And what do I have to fill in the tab classname? If I try to run the lines of code, I get a white screen...

Comment: if you share a link, i can finish the snippet for you. You have to inspect the code to get the correct class name.

Comment: The tab should go to this url: [Link] https://www.chirooostham.be/inschrijvingen/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, can you also share a link to a member profile page?

Comment: Here you go: [Link] https://www.chirooostham.be/user/jcd/?profiletab=main&um_action=edit

Comment: I can't see any tabs, are you sure it's set to public? I have to see your `mycustomtab` , so make sure the `um_profile_tabs` filter is running.

Comment: Try this one: [Link] https://www.chirooostham.be/user/jasper-camps-2/?profiletab=main, the other wasn't set public.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you test? You shoudn't get a white screen though? Make sure u use the snippet plugin correctly.

Comment: When I try to save the new snippet, I still get a white screen. In the new snippet, I only pasted the jquery code

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to close the snippet correctly, see updated snippet.

Comment: Hey Bjorn,

The problem remains, still a white screen when clicking on the tab.

Comment: I can't see the script, are you certain you set the snippet plugin correctly?

Comment: I use Code Snippet, what can I possibly do wrong with the set-up?

Comment: Ah, that plugin is for PHP only. Use [this one](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/). The code i provided is javascript. Btw. i recommend version 2, i think it will work better.

Comment: Glad i could help. Please set my answer as accepted i you liked my solution. Thanks!